# Hide keyboard each time I'm using an Edittext

Tags: android

When I start my activity the getwindow() call works well. What I want to achieve is to enter some text, hit the button to reset the edittext and then hide the keyboard. The real code is more complicated, but thi is what I want to do.
I tried to place the call getwindow() inside the button call but it doesn't hide the keyboard.
I've read through the different threads so I tried the other methodmanager solution but I get the same result.

What do you recommend I do?

Thanks!

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

    final Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
            EditText etxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxt);
            etxt.setText("");
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use InputMethodManager ans set it to your layout.

```
LinearLayout mainLayout; \\or whatever layout u have
mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);

InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mainLayout.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

This will work for all the edittexts in that particular layout

For a particular edit text, just use these 2 lines like this:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

And if your edittext is the first thing that get focus when activity starts, then u can hide the keyboard by puttin this code in onCreate :

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: glad i could help. mark the answer as correct it will help others with the same proble and me for reputation :p..... happy programming

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow. I think I did it. mark went green :)